# How to parse JSON data in iOS

Tags: ios, json

I am getting response from server in this format

```
{updated_at: 12345555 dates:
    [{"start_date": "2014-03-02", "end_date": "2014-03-02"},
     {"start_date": "2014-04-02", "end_date": "2014-04-02"},
     {"start_date": "2014-05-02", "end_date": "2014-05-02"}]}
```

I want to parse this information and add it to 2 NSmutableArrays, I am not understanding how to do this

I tried this

```
NSMutableArray *startDate = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *endDate = [NSMutableArray array];

[dictionaries enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    [startDate addObject:[obj valueForKeyPath:@"start_date"]];
    [endDate addObject:[obj valueForKeyPath:@"end_date"]];

}];
```

But I get error saying that the key is invalid. I am not understanding where I am going wrong.

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes to learn, and then things make a lot more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{}`: means NSDictionary

`[]`: means NSArray

```
 NSArray *dates = [yourJsonData objectForKey:@"dates"];
 for(NSDictionary *data in dates){
    [startDate addObject: [data objectForKey: start_date];
    [endDate addObject: [data objectForKey: end_date];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to enumerate `NSDictionary` while you have `NSArray`. Your `dictionaries` object should be of type `NSArray` then

```
for(int i = 0; i<dictionaries.count; i++)
{
  [startDate addObject:[obj valueForKeyPath:@"start_date"]];
  [endDate addObject:[obj valueForKeyPath:@"end_date"]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the shown data is what you get, then it's not valid JSON.

In JSON, the keys need to be quoted and there needs to be a comma between key/value pairs:

```
{"updated_at": 12345555 dates:
    [{"start_date": "2014-03-02", "end_date": "2014-03-02"},
     {"start_date": "2014-04-02", "end_date": "2014-04-02"},
     {"start_date": "2014-05-02", "end_date": "2014-05-02"}]}
```

Comment: Hey actually my documentation has not been updated, but I am getting response as you have written above. I will just update it